# Let $x,y$ and $n$ be positive integers, show that: $x^n-y^n=(x^{\frac{n}{2}}+y^{\frac{n}{2}})(x^{\frac{n}{2}}-y^{\frac{n}{2}})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The structure of the equation (from the statement) has a semblance of the algebraic identity: $$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$ and that's the only hint I got from my observation, so I need your help again.

Regards

Comment: Compute the RHS?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your Question! Can you explain a bit? @GitGud

Comment: RHS means right-hand side. Just simplify the expression and note that you get the left side.

Comment: @Git Gud - that's why I said "lefthand side" :D

Comment: @user... Git Gud meant, "multiply it out", expand the righthand side, see what you get (4 terms), and see if you can reduce/simplify it to the lefthand side.

Comment: Are there some restrictions on the sign of $x,y?$ If not, are you allowed to work with complex numbers?

Comment: Not my question so I couldn't say if the value of the expression can be complex or is required/assumed to be real. I assume we're working in $\mathbb{R}$, so some restrictions *do* apply, e.g. $x, y \ge 0$. I doubt everything is supposed to be integer, otherwise $\frac n 2$ should be more explicit, e.g. *floor* of that quotient.

Comment: If you are assuming $x,y\ge 0$ your question have been answered. If not, some problems appear. For example, if $x=-2,y=1,n=3.$

Comment: @mfl I updated my answer to cover ambiguities.

Comment: hint: $n = 2\cdot\frac{n}{2}$

Comment: $x, y$ and $n$ is positive integers @mfl I edited my question

Comment: I'm not sure if the integers could be real or complex but I only tested it with positive integers. @BrianO

Comment: There are no "real or complex integers" that aren't just... integers. But ok :) Anyway, you said in the headline that everything's an integer. What we puzzled over was whether $x$ or $y$ could be negative with $n$ odd. But as I indicated in the last paragraph, I think the point of the identity is: if you can get things in the form of the RHS, then you can rewrite it as the LHS and you don't have to worry about those issues. Feel free to say the answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

So substitute $a \leftarrow x^{\frac{n}{2}}, b \leftarrow y^{\frac{n}{2}}$ into the identity you cite, $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$, and simplify the lefthand side using $(u^v)^w = u^{(v w)}$.

I assume that the expressions on the righthand side, involving possibly fractional exponents ($n$ odd), are computed in an appropriate structure ($\mathbb{R}$, or even $\mathbb{C}$ if $x$ or $y$ can be *negative* integers). The identity that you're proving shows you that in any case the end result is a (nonnegative or negative) integer, even if, say, $n = 3$ or $x = -1$; you don't have to worry about (= compute) the perhaps "weird" intermediate values.

Comment: What happens if $x=-1$ and $n=3?$

Comment: I don't really care :) I assume all things involved are members of structures where the operations make sense. If we should care then OP should state constraints.

Comment: I agree with your answer. I have formulated the question to the OP.

Comment: @mfl Probably best to not overthink this one.